# Google BigQuery load from GCS fails with error Unsupported empty struct type for field

Tags: json, google-bigquery

We have been running jobs for the last few months that load json data from GCS to BigQuery. on 6/29/2019 it started failing with the error message

{'reason': 'invalid', 'message': "Unsupported empty struct type for field 'field_2'"}

There has been no change to the job parameters or the structure of the json. 
The data does contain json with an empty object like so

```
{
"field_1":"value_1",
"field_2":{},
"field_3":{"field_3_1":"value_3_1"},
"field_4":"value_4"
}
```

But the data has always had this empty object and loaded fine for months.
With a google search, I couldn't find any results with that error message.

redacted output that shows the load options i'm using.

````
    'createDisposition': 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_APPEND',
    'sourceFormat': 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    'ignoreUnknownValues': True,
    'autodetect': True,
    'schemaUpdateOptions': ['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION', 'ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION']
}, 'jobType': 'LOAD'
}, 'status': {
    'errorResult': {
        'reason': 'invalid',
        'message': "Unsupported empty struct type for field 'field_2'"
    },
    'errors': [{
            'reason': 'invalid',
            'message': "Unsupported empty struct type for field 'field_2'"
        }
    ],
    'state': 'DONE'
}
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

What is the existing schema for your field2?  Does it have field names or is it nullable?

Run this query in the BQ interface:

```
select 123 as field1, STRUCT(NULL) as field2
```

View the JSON output or save the table and view the schema.  `field2` has a structure within it.

Now run:

```
select 123 as field1, STRUCT() as field2
```

It seems unlikely that you ever would have allowed an empty struct.  A struct is akin to a normal row in a table (although nested in this case).  What does an empty row look like?  If you imagine my first example as a row that you could query, you would get 1 column with a null value.  For the second query, that row wouldn't exist...there is no values or column name.  The struct has no structure!